# Adding new row to datatable's top

Tags: asp.net, datatable, datarow

When we use datatable.newrow command, a new empty row added to bottom of rows. However I want newrow to added to top of datatable. How can I make it?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You use the NewRow to create a row with the same columns.  To actually get it into the DataTable, you've got to do

```
myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(myDataRow, 0);
```

Where 0 is the index you want to insert it at.

Comment: myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(myDataRow,0); is the correct form. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

Here is the best example to add row in table

```
DataRow newRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
newRow[0] = "0";
newRow[1] = "Select one";
myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);
```

It's set the row on first

Comment: Thank you, this is a little more helpful than the accepted answer

Comment: @CoryBaumer  Ohh its my pleasure to... :)

Answer (score 3):

This One is Wrong

```
myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(0,myDataRow);
```

Please use the below line instead of that

```
myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(myDataRow,0);
```

Comment: I have written correct form as a comment of accepted answer. You can see it above.